# Visual Studio Git commit not in local history

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022
I made a local commit:
[image]

When I check the history, the commit is not there:

[image]

It worked many times before I upgraded VS from 2019 to 2022. Could anyone offer a tip on how to remedy this?

**Edit 2022-06-07**

I used [Git Gui](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) to check the folder and VS solution and it shows a complete list of all the commits with every commit that I have made. This looks like the VS has trouble displaying the history.

VS info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (2)
Version 17.2.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.2.3+32526.322
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C++ 2022   00483-10700-25814-AA515
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.2.392.13739
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.2.392.13739
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.2.392.13739
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.2.0-4.22252.24+47cdc16a21bbb8a4aadfb666b011e2059e1be5d2
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.2.20 (482eb2a)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.2.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   17.0.32314.00
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2218101+885a343b00bcab620a90c1550c37dafd730ce984
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62204.01010
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.10418.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.2.0-4.22252.24+47cdc16a21bbb8a4aadfb666b011e2059e1be5d2
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.22253.3+058e7a7e597a02c129f38742f250a4b212da9ee3
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Xamarin   17.2.0.175 (d17-2@e4ffdc0)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.2.0.244 (remotes/origin/d17-2@197e1a0b7)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.2.15 (2e3b60e)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   12.3.0.3 (d17-2/bbba5a2)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
Mono: adf1bc4
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-2@9760f0a9
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.2@7b1e016
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-2@fc3c2ac

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.10.0.1 (568bdb24e)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: It seems to show it under the Outgoing tab rather than the local history: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7zxx.png  I never use Git in Visual Studio, so I don't know what it use to do/if this changed at all.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. How can I make a local commit?

Comment: Haven't you already? I see you have 13 outgoing commits listed.  Those should be your local commits.

Comment: Why do I have two lists: local commits and outgoing?  I have deleted the remote, now I do not have the outgoing. I still cannot make a local commit as I did before.

Comment: "outgoing" commits are local commits that you haven't pushed yet. Every time you make a commit on your machine, it is a local commit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I do not need the remote one, so I deleted it. I do not see the outgoing list now. I have made multiple commits but still do not see the commits in the local history.

Comment: Visual Studio has different views for branches. The main one auto-refreshes, but opening a separate window for branch history does not. Perhaps you are viewing a specific branch history window and simply need to press the refresh button.

Comment: I refreshed many times. I have only the master branch and only local. Everything was working fine with VS2019.